# cryptography in python: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes

Tags: python-3.x, python-cryptography

I am trying to make a login interface in a command prompt,

```
def login():
    key_file_path = "etc/keys/key.key"

    # Read the key from the file
    with open(key_file_path, "rb") as key_file:
        key = key_file.read()

    cipher_suite = Fernet(key)

    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")

    user_file_path = "etc/users/" + username + ".usr"

    # Check if the file exists for the provided username
    if os.path.exists(user_file_path):
        with open(user_file_path, "rb") as file:
            # Decrypt the stored password
            enc = file.read()
            stored_password = cipher_suite.decrypt(enc).decode()

            # Check if the decrypted password matches the user input
            if stored_password == password:
                print("Login successful!")
                user_terminal(username)
            else:
                print("Incorrect password. Please try again.")
    else:
        print("Error: User not found.")
```

problem is, cryptography does not like this...

> ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.

The key is:
b'ckUS_DFMD3P_t14204IndtLhHokAaQrFT48aY4TF2JU='

reinstalled cryptography, regenerated the key

Comment: Thats not a good way to do password authentication, you should look at `passlib` instead (https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ ).

Comment: 1) Please post the full traceback.  2) Please post the contents of the key file; the *complete* output of `cat -vet`.  3) Shouldn’t the path be `/etc` (note the forward slash), as *presumably* your `etc` directory is off of root, not the cwd.

Comment: @schlenk - I’d never hope to see this is a production system. On the other hand, at least the OP is not validating against a plaintext password file, as we see so much. Perhaps they are doing a bit of research into how password hashing and key encryption works.  If that’s the case, well done them!